recovering from a failed upgrade I have an issue with RST not covered in the manual
I'm running single boot version 24 sort of, (had errors on the 22 upgrade). a recent update had a slew of dpkg python errors and the system now hangs on boot. No problem as I have my files backed up so I grab the USB I used for the 22 install a year ago and prepare to reinstall everything but the process stalls on RST, odd as I've already installed Ubuntu with this stick before but I check BIOS settings and they are on AHCI already. Which is fortunate because the BIOS doesn't have an option to change anything about SSD. This isn't covered by the docs so here I am.
